# Avoid duplicating data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables called **room_type** and **resve_room**.

The **room_type** table has room numbers `5, 3, 6 ,9 ,10`. The **resve_room** table has room numbers `3 and 9`.

How can I write an SQL query that filters out reserved room number 3 and 9 from the **room_type** table. I want to return the following room numbers `5,6,10`.

I have tried using the following SQL but it only returned `3 and 9` :

```
SELECT room_type.room_no 
FROM room_type,in_hand_room 
WHERE in_hand_room.room_no=room_type.room_no 
&& room_type.room_id='$room_id
```

Comment: Anything you tried in particular? It's really hard to think of something easier in programming than what you asked about.

Comment: hey i need to display room number 5 , 6 , 10 except 3 and 9

Comment: i try with SELECT room_type.room_no FROM room_type,in_hand_room WHERE in_hand_room.room_no=room_type.room_no &&  room_type.room_id='$room_id

Comment: Now it's time to explain your tables structure

Comment: The SQL you provided is pulling data from different tables than the ones provided in your question? Where does `in_hand_room` come into play. You need to post information in your question about your table structures.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
   SELECT B.Accountid 
  FROM TableB AS B 
  LEFT 
  JOIN TableA AS A 
    ON A.ID = B.Accountid 
   AND A.ID IS NULL;
```

Or maybe this

```
select ids from TableB EXCEPT select id from TableA
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `EXCEPT` as far as I know, but you can use `NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM TableA)`

Answer (score 1):

Try the follwoing

```
 SELECT room_type.room_no 
 FROM room_type 
 WHERE  room_type.room_no NOT IN (SELECT resve_room.room_no from resve_room )
```

or  in_hand_room instead of  resve_room beacuse it 's not clear from your desc which one is your reservation table

Comment: resve_room is the reservation table

Comment: yes,,,it is working,,,,,,,,thank you all of you,,,,you save me,,,,again thank you very much,,,,,geoandri specially you